# How to initialize an object and set attributes from scratch with Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'd like to have this object called `foo` and I'd like `foo` to have `name`and `otherattr`

I was thinking of trying something like

```
foo = nil
foo.name = "lalala"
foo.otherattr = "lelele"
```

But I keep getting

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
```

I don't want to use models I want this just to be on `runtime`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Objects at Run-time in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775190/creating-objects-at-run-time-in-ruby)

Comment: Pete's answer is working pretty good for me !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an OpenStruct to get this type of behavior. You said you "don't want to use model" but I'm not sure exactly what you mean by that. Using an OpenStruct will allow you to get the functionality you want without writing your own class at least:

```
require 'ostruct'
foo = OpenStruct.new
foo.name = "lalala"
foo.name
=> "lalala"
```

Comment: I think Pete's referring to Rails' models.

Comment: Yes I Think he is, in fact i was doing this on a Ruby on Rails App, so i tried this and It's working perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a class, you can do this:

```
foo = Object.new
class << foo
  attr_accessor :name, :other
end

foo.name = "bar"
puts foo.name
```